# spring @value annotation returns null with non static variable

Tags: java, spring, properties

I need to read the value from my application.properties file and I've tried this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "myservice")
public class MailServiceAuthProvider {
    @Value("${my.name}")
    private String name;

    public void myMethod()
    {
      System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

my application.properties in the resource folder of the same package :

`my.name=name`

but this is always null

I've even tried not to read from the properties file but directly give the value `@Value("default-name")`
in the annotation, but it is also null.

I've read some tutorials and some posts there and they're using the same configuration. What am I doing wrong?

UPD I've instantiated MailServiceAuthProvider as following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App() implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    MailServiceAuthProvider a;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        a.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: is MailServiceAuthProvider inside myservice package as would your component scan suggests? You can try to annotate your class with only Component and try again. Also make sure you've imported the correct Value annotation for spring which is import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

Comment: how MailServiceAuthProvider is instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've finally solved the issue. The problem was that I instantiated MailServiceAuthProvider with keyword new:

```
MailServiceAuthProvider instance = new MailServiceAuthProvider();
instance.myMethod();
```

, but instead, I should use @Autowired like that:

```
@Autowired
MailServiceAuthProvider instance;

//...some code
instance.myMethod();
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Component` instead of `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "myservice")` so that you can make `MailServiceAuthProvider` a Spring-managed Bean:

```java
@Component
public class MailServiceAuthProvider {
    @Value("${my.name}")
    private String name;

    public void myMethod()
    {
      System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have something like the following main class in the base package of your application, you don't even need `@ComponentScan` annotation.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Why? Because `@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub-packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.